# Using simple fragments in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

### I am working on simple fragments in android

---

**fragment_1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/Yellow" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="This is the fragment part"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Fragment1.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);


        return view;
    }



}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.example.simplestfragment.Fragment1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

**I am getting output as**::

[image]

- As we can see there are white spaces on left,right & top of fragment
- How to remove them to get output as below

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the padding from your layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.example.simplestfragment.Fragment1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

remove this lines..

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**activity_main.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mukundwn.fragments.MainActivity">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/listview"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="190dp"/>



</RelativeLayout>


**MainActivity.java**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView lv;
    String days[]={"Modi","Rajnikanth","BinLaden","Mukund"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        ArrayAdapter<String> ada=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,days);
        lv.setAdapter(ada);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                TextView txt = (TextView) view;


               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "u have selected " + txt.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if( ((TextView) view).getText().toString().equals("Modi"))
                    loadFragment(new BlankFragment());
                if(txt.getText().toString().equals("Rajnikanth"))
                    loadFragment(new BlankFragment2());
                if(txt.getText().toString().equals("BinLaden"))
                    loadFragment(new BlankFragment3());
                else if(txt.getText().toString().equals("Mukund"))
                    loadFragment(new BlankFragment4());
            }
        });

    }

//    private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment)
//    {
//        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
//        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
//        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment);
//        fragmentTransaction.commit();
//    }

    public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment)
    {
        FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.